# Registry System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, .net, registry

when I'm trying to create a subkey in Registry.ClassesRoot I get an System.UnauthorizedAccessException! I'm using win7. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your program run as administrator.
By default win7 does not run programs with admin permissions.

Comment: but how can I make my program from the beginning run as admin?

Comment: F.Y.I.:  in order to test from within Visual Studio 2010 under Windows 7, I start vs2010 via right click, Run As Administrator.

Answer (score 4):

Because only people in the Administrator group can create keys under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

In general, you shouldn't need to be creating keys under there (if it's part of an install process, then you should probably be using a proper installer with transaction and rollback support - such as Windows Installer - not rolling your own).

But to solve your *specific* problem, then you need to run your application as Administrator.